# Rails: Convert all values that match into null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have a table with a lot of data. Specific column in which I want to replace values is decimal data type. I want to replace all values that are `0` into `null`. How to do that with Rails migrations? I want to do same thing for columns of date type that match for example `1111-11-11`.

Comment: Are you changing the structure of your schema or just trying to change the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, migrations are used to change the structure of the database, not its content.

To update all rows matching a value:

```
Model.where(column_name: 0).update_all(column_name: nil)
```

You could do the same thing with the date type:

```
Model.where(date: '1111-11-11').update_all(column_name: nil)
```

You could put these in a migration, but a rake task might be a more appropriate location.